# restart function scroll on resizing

Tags: javascript, scroll, vue.js, resize

I'm trying to run a scroll function on desktop. I perform calculations to position a block on the page according to the user's screen size.

I'm looking in all directions, I do not see how to do that when I resize the size of the screen the function is restarted.

```
methods: {
  handleScroll: function() {
    let hW = $(window).height();
    let WW = $(window).width();

    let position = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (
          scroll > position
          &&  WW >= 768
      ){
       // thing...
        console.log('down');
      } else if(
          scroll < position
          && WW >= 768
       // thing...

      ){
       // thing...
        console.log('up')
      }
      position = scroll;
    });
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.handleScroll();
}
```

Comment: listen for "resize" event and pass `handleScroll` as a callback

Comment: couldn't this be bad for user experience? If i click on a link that leads me to a section, and keep on reading with scrolling down, i wouldn't want that a window resize takes me back each time to the beginning of that section..

Comment: These lines do not work :
`
    mounted () {
      this.handleScroll();
      window.addEventListener(‘resize’, this.handleScroll);
    },`

Comment: it's a one page i wish to fixed a block for a few hundred px